# Extract Mac address from output

Tags: sed, awk, cut

I am trying to get only the mac address from the below output. Its a script that runs and connects to a Cisco switch.

```
switch#show ip arp x.x.x.x
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  xx.x.x.x             128   xxxx.xxxx.xxxx  ARPA   Vlanx
```

I have tried using `cut` and `sed` with no joy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To get the fourth field on a line that starts `Internet`:

```
awk '/^Internet/{print $4}'
```